# Xcode live canvas has different behaviour compared to the real complied version

Tags: ios, xcode, canvas, swiftui

Currently running iOS 15 (Xcode 13). 
I'm trying to dismiss views after a navigation link. After coding, I tried it using the Xcode canvas feature. When clicking the "Done" button in the toolbar, expected behaviour occurred. The view dismissed.
However when I compiled the app, by running it on an actual phone. The "Done" but ceases to work as expected (unlike the Xcode Canvas)

***Code used to dismiss:***

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
     Button("Done") {
          print("go back")
          self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
     }
}
```

The links below are to videos showing how the behaviours differ:
[Xcode Live Canvas behaviour](https://vimeo.com/564652962)
[Complied on real iPhone behaviour](https://vimeo.com/564655470)

If someone could explain why this occurs / how I could fix it that would be brilliant.

Thanks, 
Bradley :)

Comment: Make sure you're not using one `NavigationView` inside another one...

Comment: If possible, provide, a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Agree with above. Need a [mre] to debug this.